# Help with password

Tags: password

Recently, my husband found a laptop in an apartment (he does maintenance and this person left behind all kinds of electronics). The laptop works, but it has ubuntu installed and its asking for a password. How can I either bypass the password or install a new operating system?

---

Sony Vaio model # PCG-71312L
Was running Windows 8 from what I can tell but I think it was replaced with ubuntu. There is no option to boot the windows op system anymore.

Comment: why do you want to bypass the password...?

Comment: Someone left it in an empty apartment. It's useless to me right now bc I can't get past the password to use the laptop.

Comment: @muru: i don't think so, since i guess `unlock disk sda5_crypt` from the first comment of the answer indicates a full disk encryption.

Comment: @DJ Then https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/158442 and wipe the disk, I suppose.

Comment: how about returning the laptop to his owner...? ;-)

Comment: As stated in my first question...my husband works at an apartment complex. After 30 days, anything left behind no longer belongs to that person. It's property of the complex. He can do as he pleases. They have been gone for 2 months. They left the laptop, monitors, hard drives, clothes...you name it, they left it. It seems if they wanted it, they would have came back for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to boot from a CD or bootable USB and install a new operating system (eg. Windows), unless the BIOS/UEFI is password protected.

Comment: I have a windows xp disc. It's definitely old, but wanted to try it anyway. It won't load it. It just takes me to the ubuntu screen and asks to please unlock disk sda5_crypt. I am not very tech savvy so I don't know how to navigate any of this.

Comment: It would help to have some specifications on the laptop, a model no.

Comment: After a quick check, you may try pressing the F2 key as the VAIO logo appears. Page 125 of the manual here: https://docs.sony.com/release//VPCEB1_series_EN_CA.pdf

Comment: Ok. So that's a new screen I haven't seen before. What am I looking for here?

Comment: Following the manual, you need to change the boot order to make the laptop boot into the CD first. After saving changes, you should boot into your copy of Windows XP.

Comment: Ok. Let me see what I can figure out here. I surely appreciate your help. I'll probably be back haha! Thank you again!

Comment: Also, you may have to change the boot order again later after you've finished installing a new operating system. No probs !

Comment: I'm back. How long does it normally take to boot from a cd? I changed the boot order. Exited setup and saved changes. It went to black screen that says to boot from cd press any key. Done. Another setup memo popped up but was gone in a split second. Now I'm sitting at a black screen. Is this normal?

Comment: **Do not** install Win XP. It hasn't had any security updates since Apr. 2015, and it would be extremely dangerous to use today

Comment: I do agree with @android. You would be better off installing another linux distribution or a later version of Windows.

Comment: I finally got windows 8 to begin the install process. The disc was left with all the other things. However, there is no product key to finish installation. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

just a brief summary of the steps to do:

1. forget to bypass the "ubuntu-password"...! - you don't need to, if you don't want to read the stored data.
2. create a bootable medium with an other pc: i would suggest a usb with a current lts-version of ubuntu or its derivatives; or if it has to be windows, take 7 or up (windows xp is likely not to work - beside the security-concerns)!
3. go to the locked pc an attach/insert the bootable medium.
4. try to access the BIOS/UEFI or at least choosing the boot-medium with pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or also <kbd>DEL</kbd> is used by some manufacturers, **before** booting right after pressing the power button.

*--> if there is also a password needed to access the BIOS/UEFI (it looks different than the known ubuntu-prompt) it gets pretty complicated.*

5. in the BIOS/UEFI change the boot-order, save changes and exit; or if you entered a little menu for just selecting the boot-medium, choose the right one and your system will start your chosen OS.
6. format the whole harddisk (*btw: use GPT, not MBR like now*) and install your OS.
7. if you changed the boot order via "full BIOS/UEFI", i suggest to change it back to boot from the harddisk.